# Writing the Z combinator in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, lambda-calculus

I'm new to lambda calculus, and I find the grammar sometimes ambiguous to me.
Specifically, I'd like to know how to understand the Z combinator:

```
Z = λ f. (λ x. f (λ v. xxv)) (λ x. f (λ v. xxv))
```

How to write it in OCaml?
Updated:
I get error when writing like this:

```
 fun f-> let g = fun x -> f(fun v-> x x v)in g g;;
```

Error: This expression has type 'a -> 'b -> 'c
but an expression was expected of type 'a
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a -> 'b -> 'c

Comment: What do you find ambiguous? The syntax translates directly to OCaml (but it won’t typecheck in this case, unless you pass option `-rectypes` to OCaml). The only thing you have to understand is what the construct `λ x, …` means. You surely know how to express the same concept with OCaml syntax.

Comment: I'd like to know where to add parentheses, for example:    
does λ x. f (λ v. xxv) mean( λ x. f) (λ v. xxv) or λ x. (f (λ v. xxv))? does λ v. xxv mean λ v. (xxv) or (λ v. x)xv ?

Comment: You don’t need to change anything with respect to parentheses.

Comment: when I write 
fun f -> let g = fun x -> f fun v -> x x v in g g;;
in ocaml there is a syntax error.

Comment: And indeed, you have removed parentheses by comparison with the lambda-calculus expression: write `f (fun v -> ...)` instead of `f fun v -> ...`. So your problem really was the syntax of OCaml, not the syntax of lambda calculus.

Comment: I updated my question, pasted the error here when I add the parentheses as you said

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I already edited your post once, now your turn.

Comment: Next time you pose a question, please include what you have tried and how it failed, so that we don’t have to guess. So now your problem is typing; go back to first comment. ;-) And again, this really is a problem with OCaml and not with lambda calculus. Lambda calculus has no notion of types, so it allows to write things that do not conform to stricter type disciplines such as that of OCaml (for instance, `λ x. xx`). The option `-rectypes` to OCaml enables a feature called *recursive types* which allows more programs to be typechecked (at the cost of inferred types that can be surprising).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing the Z-combinator requires either to allow recursive types (with the `-rectypes` option) or to box the type recursion inside a type constructor:

```
type 'a fix = Fix of ('a fix -> 'a)
let z f = 
  (fun (Fix x as fx) -> f (fun v -> x fx v)) 
  (Fix (fun (Fix x as fx) -> f (fun v -> x fx v)))
```

Essentially, we are replacing

```
x x v
```

which requires `x` to accept itself as an argument which leads to the recursive type `'a -> 'b -> 'c as 'a` by

```
x fx v
```

which boxes the recursive type as `('a -> 'b) fix -> 'a -> 'b`